# Finding Sylvester sequence code

Tags: python, recursion

I've written this code to calculate the Sylvester sequence, which is defined as $$s_n = s_{n-1}(s_{n-1}-1)+1$$ where \$s_0=2\$.

```
def sylvester_term(n):
    """ Returns the maximum number of we will consider in a wps of dimension n

    >>> sylvester_term(2)
    7
    >>> sylvester_term(3)
    43
    """
    if n == 0:
        s_n = 2
        return s_n

    s_n = sylvester_term(n-1)*(sylvester_term(n-1)-1)+1

    return s_n  
    print(s_n)

print(sylvester_term(3))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `print()` call at the end of the function is unreachable and should be removed.

There's no need to assign `s_n` before returning.

PEP 8, the official Python style guide, recommends [a space before and after every binary operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements).

```
def sylvester_term(n):
    """docstring here"""
    if n == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        return sylvester_term(n - 1) * (sylvester_term(n - 1) - 1) + 1
```

Next, you should notice that `sylvester_term(n - 1)` is used twice in the expression.  You should definitely assign that result to a variable, otherwise your function will require *drastically* more time — O(2<sup>*n*</sup>) instead of O(*n*).

```
def sylvester_term(n):
    """Return the maximum number of we will consider in a wps of dimension n

    >>> sylvester_term(2)
    7
    >>> sylvester_term(3)
    43
    """
    if n == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        prev_sylvester_term = sylvester_term(n - 1)
        return prev_sylvester_term * (prev_sylvester_term - 1) + 1
```